# How to select rows based on the output of another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subset

I have two tables I am working with. The first one `QuarterDateMapping` holds information about the start and end dates of quarters:

```
GregorianQuarterName | GregorianMonthBeginDate | GregorianMonthEndDate
```

where `GregorianQuarterName` is a `nvarchar` with a string naming the quarter in the format "FY%y- Q%q" and `GregorianMonthBeginDate` and `GregorianMonthEndDate` being `datetime` objects.  The second table, `QuarterlyRevenueData`, holds the information want to query and has the format:

```
Fiscal_Quarter | Product | Revenue
```

where `Fiscal_Quarter` has the same format as `GregorianQuarterName`. I want to only return values from the second table that are at or before the current quarter.  I have figured out how to return the current quarter from the first table using:

```
SELECT QDMap.GregorianQuarterName AS most_recent_quarter 
FROM QuarterDateMapping QDMap
WHERE QDMap.GregorianMonthBeginDate <= GetDate()
AND QDMap.GregorianMonthEndDate >= GetDate()
```

which successfully returns the current quarter (FY17-Q1).  The difficulty I am having is trying to figure out how to use this output to query the second table.  I have tried:

```
;WITH QuarterData As
(
 SELECT QDMap.GregorianQuarterName AS most_recent_quarter 
 FROM QuarterDateMapping QDMap
 WHERE QDMap.GregorianMonthBeginDate <= GetDate()
 AND QDMap.GregorianMonthEndDate >= GetDate()
)
SELECT * FROM QuarterlyRevenueData revdata
WHERE revdata.Fiscal_Quarter <= QuarterData.most_recent_quarter
```

However this gives me the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>
> The multi-part identifier "QuarterData.most_recent_quarter" could not be bound.

When I run the same query as above, but with the quarter hard coded:

```
SELECT * FROM QuarterlyRevenueData revdata
WHERE revdata.Fiscal_Quarter <= 'FY17-Q1'
```

It runs as expected and returns the data I want, but I want my query to be able to update automatically.

Thank you for any help.  Let me know if my question needs more information or better formatting, this is my first SQL question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't be bound error is happening because although you create a dataset (QuarterData) you never referenced it (appropriately) within the final query... Modified your code by returning the value from the CTE within a subquery which should give you the result you're looking for!

```
WITH QuarterData As
(
    SELECT QDMap.GregorianQuarterName AS most_recent_quarter 
    FROM QuarterDateMapping QDMap
    WHERE QDMap.GregorianMonthBeginDate <= GetDate()
    AND QDMap.GregorianMonthEndDate >= GetDate()
)
SELECT * FROM QuarterlyRevenueData revdata
WHERE revdata.Fiscal_Quarter <= (SELECT most_recent_quarter FROM QuarterData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this as a join instead of a subquery.

```
SELECT
    QDM.GregorianQuarterName
    ,QDM.GregorianMonthBeginDate 
    ,QDM.GregorianMonthEndDate
    ,QRD.Fiscal_Quarter 
    ,QRD.Product 
    ,QRD.Revenue
FROM QuarterDateMapping QDM
JOIN QuarterlyRevenueData QRD
    ON QRD.Fiscal_Quarter <= QDM.GregorianQuarterName
WHERE QDM.GregorianMonthEndDate >= GETUTCDATE()
    AND QDM.GregorianMonthBeginDate < GETUTCDATE()
```

On a side note, I wouldn't use <= and >= for between. As you are comparing it to GETUTCDATE() this shouldn't be an issue, but with set dates you have the potential for overlapping. I used >= and < but as long as only one includes "=" then you should be fine.

Comment: This mostly works, but I need to remove `QDM.GregorianQuarterName, QDM.GregorianMonthBeginDate, QDM.GregorianMonthEndDate,` from the `SELECT` statement in order to get the same data out put as filtering the table. As is the output contains 3 extra columns with the data for the current quarter from `QuarterDateMapping` repeated over and over on every row.